# Фильтр поиска php

Tags: php

Как сделать отправку формы методам GET без вывода пустых инпутов
Есть например форму

```
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="name" value="Название">
   <input type="text" name="tags" value="Теги">
   <button type="button">Поиск</button>
</form>
```

При нажатии если оставить поля пустыми, то у нас получается ссылка `сайт.ру?name=&tegs=`
Как сделать, если поля не заполнено, то оно не учитывается в ссылке. Например мы заполнили название, но теги оставили пустыми, при нажатии у нас получается `сайт.ру?name=текст из инпута`

Comment: Может использовать `POST`, а если `GET` то надо использовать JS

Comment: @wcobalt можно и POST, я не знаю как, пробовал пост, он в адресную строку вообще не отправлял параметры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET-запрос с применением JavaScript:

```
<script>
function search() {
    var url = document.form.getAttribute("action");
    var modified = false;
    if(document.form.name.value.length > 0) {
        url += "?name=" + document.form.name.value;
        modified = true;
    }
    if(document.form.tags.value.length > 0) {
        if(modified === false) {
            url += "?";
        } else {
            url += "&";
        }
        url += "tags=" + document.form.tags.value;
        modified = true;
    }
    location = url;
}
</script>

<form name="form" action="./" method="get" onsubmit="search()">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Название">
    <input type="text" name="tags" value="Теги">
    <button type="submit">Поиск</button>
</form>
```

Обратите внимание, не `<button type="button">`, а `<button type="submit">`. Также для работы скрипта необходимо установить `action="./"` (или `action="./search"`, как Вам нужно).

Answer (score 1):

1) Можно использовать `POST` метод отправки. Для этого нужно изменить HTML-код примерно так:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
```

Для того чтобы получить данные отправленные `POST` в PHP, необходимо обратиться к переменной `$_POST['ключ']`. Замените все Ваши `$_GET` на `$_POST` для того чтобы начать работать с `POST`.

Comment: А как вывести в URL заполненные инпуты, чтобы если я заполнен поле Название и при нажатии у нас был URL `сайт.ру?name=текст из инпута`

Comment: @nicolaa обязательно чтобы в URL данные были? `POST` не передаёт данные через URL.

Comment: Да, хотелось бы